# Как настроить переадресацию в htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, маршрутизация, роутинг

Хочу, чтобы запросы вида:

```
site.ru/dir/value
site.ru/dir/value/
```

переадресовывались на адрес:

```
site.ru/dir/index.php?key=value
```

Что для этого нужно прописать в htaccess?

Я пробовал так:

```
RewriteRule ^dir/([^/]+)?$ /dir/index.php/?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Это работает, если в конце запроса нет слеша. А если слеш в конце, то ошибка:

```
The requested URL was not found on this server
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого потребуется проверить значение в %{HTTP_HOST}, где обычно содержится имя домена и %{REQUEST_URI} где лежит часть запрошенного URL после имени домена и до GET-параметров

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.ru$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/dir/)(value)/?$
    RewriteRule . %1index.php?key=%2 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Не работает ваше решение.

Comment: Чтобы понять в чем проблема надо рассматривать реальный пример, который не работает. Кстати, вам нужен редирект внутренний или внешний?